# What is the measure of $\measuredangle X$?

Tags: geometry

Can you help me to figure out the value of $\measuredangle X$?

[image]

I've tried using some physical simulation method to find this angle but now I would like to know if there is any mathematical solution to this problem?

### [image]

Comment: What have you tried? At least download the diagram in your question and write down names for hte different vertices in it...

Comment: [You need to see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Thanks @UmbQbify-Key20-

Comment: @DonAntonio, I've tried using some physical simulation method to find this angle but now I would like to know if there is any mathematical solution to this problem?

Comment: And that in the question... And some context.

Comment: In degrees, $\cos(x+45)=\frac{5}{|BC|}$, so $$x=\text{acos}\left(\frac{5}{|BC|}\right)-45$$ With $0<x<45$. Is this enough? What do you want $x$ in terms of?

Comment: x is a function of Fix.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that "Fix" indicates that the *directions* (not the *lengths*) of the corresponding segments are set, and that the "Fix"ed line through $C$ is perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$.

---

For generality (and because the specific length doesn't matter), I'll replace the length $5$ with $s$. Also, I'll write $p$ and $q$ for the yet-to-be-determined lengths of the "Fix"ed segments.

Now, coordinatize with $B$ at the origin:

$$A = (-2s,0) \qquad B = (0,0) \qquad C = (-s,p) \qquad D = \left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q\right) \tag1$$
The right angles at $C$ and $D$ imply
$$\begin{align}
(D-C)\cdot(B-C) = 0 &\quad\to\quad 2 p^2 - \sqrt2 p q - \phantom{3}\sqrt2 q s + 2 s^2 = 0 \tag2\\
(C-D)\cdot(A-D) = 0 &\quad\to\quad 2 q^2 -\sqrt2 p q - 3 \sqrt2 q s + 4 s^2 = 0 \tag3
\end{align}$$

Solving $(2)$ for $q$ and substituting into $(3)$ gives
$$(p - s) (p^3 - 3 p^2 s - p s^2 - s^3) = 0 \tag{4}$$
The solution $p=s$ is clearly extraneous, so the desired $p$ must be the positive real root of the second factor, giving
$$\frac{p}{s} = 1 + \frac{4}{ \sqrt[3]{6 (9+\sqrt{33})}} 
+ \frac{ \sqrt[3]{6 (9 + \sqrt{33})}}{3} = 3.38297576\ldots \tag{5}$$
Writing $X$ for the missing angle (in degrees), we have

> $$\tan(X+45^\circ) = \frac{p}{s} \quad\to\quad X = 28.53243\ldots^\circ \tag{$\star$}$$

Comment: x is a function of Fix... the question requires clarification to FIX x.:)

Comment: @Moti: *"x is a function of Fix"* ... The lengths of the Fix segments (what I call $p$ and $q$) are determined by the length of the base and the perpendicularity conditions (which give rise to my equations $(2)$ and $(3)$). So, as it turns out, their lengths as well as their directions are *fixed*, and thus also is $X$.

Comment: Do you assume that AD parallel to BC? This was not mentioned - though now I see it in the diagram. Use the cos rule for triangles to solve for x

Comment: @Moti: *"Do you assume that AD parallel to BC?"* ... More-specifically, I take those two segments to be perpendicular to $CD$, as shown in OP's figure. Apart from that, my assumptions are clearly stated. ... To "use the cos rule for triangles to solve for x", I'd need to know more lengths than are given. At some point, the solution is going to involve solving a cubic equation to get at a relevant length. Once I solved for $p$, using $\tan(X+45^\circ)=p/s$ seemed the quickest way to conclude the problem.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Wonder if you could help with some insight with regard to publishing conjecture in math.

Comment: @Moti: I don't really have any particular insights on publishing, but a site search for ["how to publish"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+publish) yields hundreds of results. (I suspect many questions have been closed for being technically off-topic here, but that hasn't stopped people from providing advice in comments or answers.) Good luck!

Comment: THX Blue! Will continue my search...:)